Problems with Permissions from CloudWatch logs because VoiceHubSSORole
I have created a skill, which I am releasing to some specific users in beta. The problem is that I want to download the logs that in JSON format that are generated, but it is not possible because it says that the user VoiceHubSSORole does not have those permissions. I don't know what to do, how to link it to the AWS account I have, for example, where I store data in the DynamoDB database or how to change the permissions of VoiceHubSSORole.
I have looked for information in the manual and tried to change the roles with an IAM user I created in my AWS account, which is related to the database account, but I can't solve this problem.

Sounds like an Alexa hosted skill. The AWS resources are so locked down with Alexa hosted that it's impossible to do anything slightly out of the ordinary.  One reason I don't use Alexa hosted. You can use your own AWS resources with Alexa hosted skills and Amazon have documentation on how to do this.  But with the upcoming withdrawal of free AWS credits then it might end up costing you $$.
